# What would happen if the Emergency Locator Transmitter was activated wrongly?

Tags: search-and-rescue

Supposing, after a "bad" landing, performing a high vertical speeed, the crew, unintentionally, activates the ELT, sending the signs to the sattelites, warning the rescue and team about the "accident", that does not happen.
Would the fees for the services be payed?
Is there any penalty for the crew or company?

Comment: On a similar note, I had a few friends who found out that an ELT they were looking for was accidentally activated on a boat.

Comment: There was a bizarre thing a few years ago where [a TV set was emitting an ELT signal](http://www.technewsworld.com/story/37435.html). They didn't charge the guy or the company, but he had to leave it off until the TV company replaced it. Apparently [normal electronics do this on a somewhat regular basis](http://www.nytimes.com/learning/teachers/featured_articles/20041102tuesday.html)

Answer (score 4):

It happens ALL the time. I have been on many airport hunts looking for the airplane with a triggered ELT. You tale a handheld radio and walk through the ramp until you find it.

Answer (score 2):

The ELT guys get a lot of false alarms. About 97% of ELT alerts are false alarms. Most false alarms are generated by bad ELTs on boats.

Neverthless, they chase them all down. The organization that does this is the Civil Air Patrol.

Legally, a person activating false alarm can be held liable for substantial fines, but in practice it is unknown for those fines to be assessed for an accidental alert. If someone was deliberately setting off an ELT, the FCC might attempt to prosecute and assess a fine, which by statute can be as much as $100,000.

Comment: The organization that chases down ELT activations is the US Coast Guard, assisted by the US Air Force through the Civil Air Patrol. See [AC 91-44A](http://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_91-44A.pdf). You can also activate an ELT during the first 5 minutes of the hour (and for 3 sweeps) for testing purposes, or at any time if arranged with the nearest tower or FSS.

Comment: @RonBeyer The CAP always finds the transmitter first. Who they call after they find it depends on where it is.

Comment: And source for the 97% claim?

Answer (score -4):

Unintentionally activation of ELT ,,1 when more than 1/2 of battery life time is passed .2 when You move ELT without putting its switch to off position , When you use a big ferromagnetic device neat to ELT , when you leave for a long time the Aircraft in a hanger without switching off or removing ELT from Aircraft , in case of unintentionally activation of ELT contact immediately the nearest ATC and inform them . Your Sincerely Rajabi 28th Nov 3022

Comment: Hi, and welcome. This answer is barely intelligible and doesn't seem to answer the question ("what would happen...?") or add any insight not already given in existing answers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).